# Extract Absolute File Path From a String

Tags: regex, grep

My sample text is:

```
evince /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/kids/Coping Skills.pdf
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --impress file:///home/ismail/Desktop/LibreOffice%20Impress.odp --splash-pipe=5
/usr/bin/gjs /usr/bin/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/kids/Coping Skills.epub
mpv /media/ismail/8TBRaid0/_IslamNaseed/_JunaidJamshed/Mera Dil Badal De.mp3
```

Here the two regex I am using are:

```
grep -o '/media/ismail/.*'
grep -o 'file:\S*'
```

However, I need a regex that will match both and I do not want to use fixed string like `/media/ismail/` as this might vary from machine to machine.

To be clear, first of all, these are Linux file paths. Secondly, my expected output is:

```
/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/kids/Coping Skills.pdf
file:///home/ismail/Desktop/LibreOffice%20Impress.odp
/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/kids/Coping Skills.epub
/media/ismail/8TBRaid0/_IslamNaseed/_JunaidJamshed/Mera Dil Badal De.mp3
```

Comment: Why the valid path `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin` is discarded?

Comment: Because these (/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin /usr/bin/gjs /usr/bin/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate) are executable. Let's say, because these start with `/usr/`.

Comment: This is for my future reference. What is working is `grep -oP '(file://)?(?<!\w)/(?!usr/).*\.\w{3,4}+')"`. I can replace `w{3,4}` with `\S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex matches your desired targets:

```
(file://)?(?<!\w)/(?!usr/).*?\.\S+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/4v883pav4887px).

As a `grep` command:

```
grep -oP '(file://)?(?<!\w)/(?!usr/).*?\.\S+'
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/SlL4NR).

The `-P` option is for *perl compatible* regex

Comment: Why does the regex not work with `echo "evince /etc/child/Freeing Your Child From Negative Thinking Powerful, Practical Strategies to Build a Lifetime of Resilience, Flexibility, and... (Tamar E. Chansky) (Z-Library).pdf" | grep -oP '(file://)?(?<!\w)/(?!usr/).*?\.\S+'`

Comment: `and...` is matching the dot and non-whitespace. Try changing `\S` to `\w`